# how does perl take my text file containing different users

Tags: regex, perl

The superadmin.txt file is in the form:

```
def
ghi
pqr
...etc
```

How would Perl read different users?
Will it be able to identify different text from superadmin.txt?
Here is the code:

```
  @prelist = ();
  @prelist = `cat ../cgi-bin/superadmin.txt`;
  foreach $prename (@prelist) {
  $prename =~s/\n//g ;
  $superadminstaff{$prename} = "Y";
```

Comment: I'm afraid this really isn't clear. In your file, what is a different user? What are you trying to achieve here? What output do you want? Please explain the format of your input file in more detail. What are `def` and `ghi`?

Comment: I've just noticed that you're storing your data file in your `cgi-bin` directory. This is a very bad idea. `cgi-bin` is intended for executable files. Data files should usually be stored outside of your web root.

Answer (score 4):

Well let's re write the code so it a) compiles, b) uses current best practice and c) doesn't fork out to `cat`

```
my @prelist = ();
my %superadminstaff = ();
open my $admin, '<', '../cgi-bin/superadmin.txt' or die "Can't open ../cgi-bin/superadmin.txt: $!\n";
chomp(@prelist = <$admin>);
@superadminstaff{@prelist} = ("Y") x @prelist;
```

So we have two variables `@prelist` and `%superadminstaff`, `@prelist` will hold each line of the file and `%superadminstaff` will end up keyed on each entry in the file.

Line 3 attempts to open the file, and if if can't will stop the script and print out a message explaining what went wrong.

Line 4 reads the file into `@prelist` and uses `chomp` to strip off the line endings. Note that `chomp` is used in preference to `chop` as the last line in the file my not have a line ending.

Line 5 uses some Perl magic called a hash slice to create entries in `%superadminstaff` for each element in`@prelist` and then uses the `x` operator to create a list containing as many `Y` elements as there are elements in `@prelist` this list of `Y`s is then assigned to the newly created elements in `%superadminstaff`.

So at the end of this code you now have `%superadminstaff` containing each entry of the file. However the order of the elements in the file will not be preserved and any duplicate entries in the file will be reduced to one entry in `%superadminstaff`.

Comment: I'd probably use `map` for that last line, because I feel it a little clearer: `my %superadminstaff = map { $_ => "Y" } @prelist;` - same result though, so it's a matter of taste.